# res.locals returns nothing, undefined

Tags: node.js, express

1. auth middleware code in which I defined app.locals.user and it shows the right details

```
// middlewares/auth-middleware.js

const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../schemas/user");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// auth middleware
module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { Authorization } = req.cookies;
  const [authType, authToken] = (Authorization ?? "").split(" ");

  if (!authToken || authType !== "Bearer") {
    res.status(401).send({
      errorMessage: "(1)require sign-in.",
    });
    return;
  }

  try {

    const { userId } = jwt.verify(authToken, "customized-secret-key");
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    app.locals.user = user;
    console.log(app.locals.user)
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(401).send({
      errorMessage: "(2)require sign-in.",
    });
  }
};
```

2. posts code(here is the problem. I get undefined from res.locals.user). I tried several options suggested here. Nothing worked.

```
    // routes/post.js
    router.post("/", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(res.locals.user)  
    //const { user } = app.locals.user;
    console.log(user)
    const { title, content } = req.body;
    console.log(title, content)
    const user_registered = await User.find({userId: user}).exec();
    console.log(user_registered)
    if (user_registered) 
        await Post.create({ title, content });
        res.json({ result: "success" });
    });
```

3. login code i checked if jwt.sign works and it does. No issues here.

```
    router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {

        //const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        //const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt)

        const { username, password } = req.body;

        const user = await User.findOne({ username });
  
        if (!user || password !== user.password) {
          res.status(400).json({
            errorMessage: "message.",
          });
          return;
        }
      
        const token = jwt.sign(
          { userId: user._id },
          "customized-secret-key",
          {expiresIn: '24h' // expires in 24 hours
}
        );
      
        res.cookie("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
        res.status(200).json({ token }); 
  
    })
```

4. apps.js file : I think it should be edited but have no idea what to

```
    //apps.js
    const express = require("express");
    const cors = require("cors");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const dotenv = require('dotenv')
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5500;
    var router = express.Router();
    const app = express();
    const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

    dotenv.config();
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))
    app.use("/auth", require("./middlewares/auth-middleware"));

    //route config 추가
    app.use("/api/posts", require("./routes/posts"));
    app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/users"));
    app.use("/api", require("./routes/comments"));



    // connect to mongoDB server
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL,)
    .then(console.log("Successfully connected to mongodb"))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))


    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
    });


module.exports = router;
```

I tried app.locals, req.locals etc. nothing worked. Probably wrong routes?

Comment: to access Object that you created in middleware, the object was send to your app. So its became `req` => `req.local`. and if it empty, than there is a problem within `findById`. it may be null or no data found.

Comment: thanks for your comment Tobok. I just added app.js script. The problem is findbyid returns the right details in "middleware" file but it doesnot in "post" file which I find odd because they both use res.locals.user / app.locals.user

Comment: than you would able to access it with `req.app.locals.user` regarding to the `middleware`